# How to expand recyclerview to full screen on scrolling?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment which contains a recyclerview but this fragment is contained within another fragment which is opened via a tablayout, shown as follows...

```
<LinearLayout.....

 <!-- Main Fragment -->
        <TabLayout
             ...
               />

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:background="@color/white">

             ....

 <!-- RecyclerView Fragment goes here -->

   </FrameLayout>
     ...

</LinearLayout>
```

I have attatched a onScrollListener which detects scrolling(Using the finger to scroll the recyclerview known as DRAGGING) and when it is settling(i.e. when the user moves the finger off the recyclerview). The code for this is below and it works...

//This method is inside the recyclerView fragment

```
  rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                //on scrolling expand fragment to full screen of activity

                if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING){

                   //Implement code for expanding fragment here 
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Dragging",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }else if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING ){ //on settling return back

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Settling",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

the code works and I have placed toast messages to show that it is detecting these gestures however I dont know how to expand recyclerview to full screen when the state is SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING and collapse when the recyclerview state is SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING.